Anti-realism in regards to the notion of grounding
There are a lot of philosophical texts on the notion of grounding, that is, the relation "X grounds Y". But what if all this is based on a mistaken notion? What if nothing grounds anything? I believe this would be an example of what is called "anti-realism". In this specific case, it would be anti-realism in regards to the notion of grounding. So, my real question is, has any philosopher argued in some text that there is no such thing as grounding, and if so, can I see some references?

From western Greek philosophy Pyrrhonism is a main scepticism school skeptical of any grounding judgement in contrast to Stoicism, you can read Sextus Empiricus' famous Outlines of Pyrrhonism...

See SEP, Metaphysical Grounding: skeptical responses and references there:"First-wave skepticism is characterized by a general concern about the intelligibility of the notion... Second-wave skeptics, by contrast, generally grant that the notion of grounding is coherent, but they think that it doesn’t belong in our theoretical toolkit in any case, as the arguments in favor of positing grounding aren’t persuasive."
